# CSS menu on two lines - Bug-Z index on IE7

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-7, z-index

On my menu, the first level menu is on two lines due to the large number of links present.

My bug is that the submenu drops below the second line of the first level.
On IE8, Firefox, Chrome I do not have this problem but on IE7 yes.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fp2VV/

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use following property with your css code.

```
Position:relative;
```